# In "How I Met Your Mother", who is Barney married to?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In the television series, "How I Met Your Mother", who is Barney Stinson married to?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's **Robin**:

[image: Robin] <sup>[[Source](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Barney%27s_Wedding)]</sup>

From [TV Guide](http://www.tvguide.com/News/HIMYM-Finale-Barney-Bride-Craig-Thomas-1047516.aspx) (May 2012):

> *"It had to be Robin."*
>
> That's what *How I Met Your Mother* co-creator/showrunner Craig Thomas says about Barney's big bride reveal on Monday's Season 7 finale.
>
> *"There was just no other way," he tells TVGuide.com. "We always knew it was gonna be Barney (Neil Patrick Harris) and Robin (Cobie Smulders)."*

[...]

> **Q:** *When did you and Carter [Bays] decide that Barney and Robin will get married?*
>
> **Craig Thomas:** *We decided literally years ago. As we were breaking them up, we knew there would be a rekindling and that wouldn't be the real deal ... and we would reveal them to be the groom [in the Season 6 finale] and bride now. ... Season 8 is gonna be filling in the steps between Point A and Point B. We know they do get married, but there are a lot of steps between Point A and Point B....*

Comment: As of the end of the show, this is the wrong answer.

Comment: @Hashim - Even though it's not evident in the question, it refered to the __Season 7 finale__.

Comment: It did at the time, but the Stack Exchange policy is generally to update answers to questions over time, so as to make them definitive references for the current day rather than a fixed point in time, which is only so useful.

Comment: @Hashim - But the question was specific to the Season 7 finale, it wasn't a general question about who Barney will ultimately end up with (such a question would have been off-topic, because at that point it wasn't even know how many more seasons the show would go on). -
 Barney's bride in that scene was Robin, that didn't change. And the quotes from Craig Thomas show, that this had been planned for quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

Update on accepted answer as now more seasons are released.

Barney get married to Robin in last season (Season 9) [Episode 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_the_Aisle)

> As the wedding begins, Barney has one last panic attack, which Marshall ends with the final slap of the slap bet. The ceremony goes through without any trouble, even with the arrival of a bear as the ring bear (though Barney cancels the flower gorilla at the last moment) and concludes with Robin and Barney married before their family and friends.

In finale, it is revealed that they got divorced after 3 years, season 9 [Episode 23](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Forever)

> Barney and Robin reveal that her constant traveling for work put a strain on them, and after three years of marriage, they have divorced.